# I am Facing issue in magento timezone when someone place order.

Tags: php, magento

Timezone Issue is inside the order email.

I put My code which returns date like :

**Code :**

$created =  Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAt(), 'long', true);

**O/P :**

March 31, 2016 9:10:33 AM **EDT**

But I want to Need Date Like Based on EST Timezone :

**EST** - Timezone with proper

So please any one can help me how can i achieve this and also first priority to magento code and second one PHP.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Login as admin and navigate to `System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone` and change timezone from there

Comment: Thanks for your replay
I have already done this thing but that timezone return date like "EDT".
So can you tell me from dropdwon which timezone i select so that return "EST"?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Magento or it's names of time zones but I am sure you could find something thats within the EST. Try finding `America/Massachusetts` or `America/New_York`. Those two are ESTs.